# Steps: WSO2 Authentication and Authorization = Many Steps

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to give security to my APIs using WSO2 API Manager. I could achieved the configuration of WSO2 Identity Server to use an LDAP server with some users and made WSO2 API Manager to use this Identity Server as Key Manager. My questions are:

1. How can I configure end user to access an API? Is it needed to associate all the users to an application role in API Manager carbon?
2. The end users need to have two access token to access an API? One to authenticate in IS using (OAuth Client Key/OAuth Client Secret) and other to generate the access token to the API in API Manager using (Consumer Client Id/Consumer Client Secret)?
3. Is there any tutorial explaining all this steps and how to protect an API just for some users?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the token generation flow is different from grant type to grant type. For example, the jwt-bearer grant type that you are using to generate an access token has several steps such as,

1. Service provider requests the JWT from the IDP
2. Generating an access token from API Manager exchanging the JWT assertion.

This is because the usage of each grant type is different and using grant types depends on your security requirement.

The JWT Bearer grant is usually used in client apps, where user logs in providing user name and password and the rest are done in the application itself without any interaction with the end-user.

If you need to generate the token as the end-user, you can use the password grant type.

Comment: I'm using the two types: password and jwt-bearer. 1) - request in WSO2 IS using password grant type to generate the token. 2) - request in WSO2 AM using jwt-bearer type and using access token generated by the first request. 3) - Request in WSO2 AM passing access token generated by the second request in Authorization header. I'm using a React Application in front, so I think I will chain all these calls to be transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that I made to configure WSO2 Identity Server and WSO2 Api Manager:

1. I've created a Service Provider in Identity Server and configured an OAuth/OpenId Connect.  This generated an OAuth Client Key and OAuth Client Secret.
2. I've created an Identity Provider in API Manager, import a Public Certificate to authenticate the response from identity provider and use the OAuth Client Key as Alias to be checked by WSO2 API Manager when verifying the JWT Token.
3. I've created an API in WSO2 API Publisher, associated this API to an Interna/subscriber role and my end users to this role.
4. I've created an Application in WSO2 API Store to consume my Rest Service and subscribed my API to this Application.

I followed this article to these steps:
[how-to-protect-your-apis-with-self-contained-acces](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-protect-your-apis-with-self-contained-acceshttps://)

**The problem are the steps to consume the Rest Service.**

1. Request in WSO2 Identity Server to generate an access token to API Manager:
   curl -u (OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY:OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET) -k -d "grant_type=password&username=END_USER_USERNAME&password=END_USER_PASSWORD" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
2. Request in API Manager to generate an access token to the API.
   curl -i -X POST -u (CONSUMER_KEY:CONSUMER_SECRET) -k -d 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=IS_ACCESS_TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' https://localhost:9444/oauth2/token
3. Request to API Manager to get the resource from API:
   curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer AM_ACCESS_TOKEN" http://172.19.0.1:8281/jwt/1.0.0/REST_API

**Is there any easy way to accomplish these steps?**

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the API security section in the documentation for more information on securing an API using roles, scopes, and tokens.

- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/api-authentication-overview/
- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/authorization/api-authorization/

[This doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/oauth2/grant-types/overview/) consists of information on how you can use different grant types with APIM and IS according to your requirements.

Comment: I was following this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-protect-your-apis-with-self-contained-acces but it doesn't explain how will be the end users call.